# Transplant date palm with no root ball?

Tags: roots, transplanting, palm, damage, areca-palm

I have acquired a large palm for free which was being given away by my neighbour.

I assume it is some kind of date palm after researching online.  My question is whether a palm of this size is likely to survive being transplanted with no root ball? I was surprised when the palm had no obvious roots, but my neighbours advice was to plant it within a shallow crater in the soil and that roots will form from the base.  I am somewhat sceptical but we have given it a go! The palm was free so happy to try it out.

I have no experience with palms, so any advice would be appreciated:
Is the palm likely to survive and produce roots?
Is there anything specific I should be doing now that the palm has been transplanted to increase chances of survival?

p.s. I am located in London, UK. Hardiness Zone 9a.

[image: Palm before being planted]

[image: Base of palm with no obvious rootball]

[image: Transplant site]

[image: Palm after transplant]

Answer (score 2):

I have a date palm grown from date pits and it has a vigorous root system.  So much so that I have to trim two or three inches of roots of every year from the bottom of the root ball.

These are tough plants so you have nothing to lose by planting it and seeing what happens.

Provide lots of water as the soil you have appears to be free draining and plant in full sun.